# Cannot stretch svg background image, aspect ratio will be preserved

Tags: css, svg

I am using svg as background image and I want it to be stretched to 100% 100%.

However, it seems like both Chrome and firefox are doing their best to retain the aspect ratio of the svg and instead shrink it in the other width.

*Normal size*

```
div
{
    background: url(image.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 14rem;
    height: 4rem;
}
```

[image: Normal size]

*Double width*

```
div
{
    background: url(image.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 28rem;
    height: 4rem;
}
```

[image: Double as wide]

*Double height*

```
div
{
    background: url(image.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 14rem;
    height: 8rem;
}
```

[image: Double height]

How can I instead have that svg stretched?

svg contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Lager_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 371.7 102.8" enable-background="new 0 0 371.7 102.8" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#EF9104" points="370.4,100.5 0,100.5 0,0 269.4,0 "/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Removing viewBox helped me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should add

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

to your SVG.

[**MDN Reference Link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

> `<none>`
>
> Do not force uniform scaling. Scale the graphic content of the given element non-uniformly if necessary such that the element's bounding box exactly matches the viewport rectangle.

Comment: I'm working on a pseudo-element and I can't stretch the svg (in a background image as well). It will allow to crop it, but the ratio is always preserved.

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate that this is an old question but I was having issues with this so wanted to post some further information in case it helps anyone else...

`<svg preserveAspectRatio="none">` this **only** works when a viewBox attr is provided, for instance:
 `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1920 1152">`

"preserveAspectRatio only applies when a value has been provided for viewBox on the same element. For these elements, if attribute viewBox is not provided, then preserveAspectRatio is ignored."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [SVG Fragment Identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) if you don't want to edit the SVG file itself to remove the viewBox or add preserveAspectRatio="none"

For example

```
div
{
    background: url(image.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 28rem;
    height: 4rem;
}
```

Comment: appending `#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))` to the end with `background-size: 100% 100%:` worked! however, using no-repeat it didn't load at all. So I removed that, and it's perfect. And to anyone viewing this, if you want to control the height, use `background-size: 100% HeightValueHere;`

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to hear it, like me, just now... because I haven't finished my coffee...

Make sure `preserveAspectRatio="none"` is on your top-level `svg` element (rather than directly on the `path` or `shape`).

/facepalm